# Single-word adjective for "which should be repaired"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

I'm looking for a term to characterise things which *should* be repaired. I am also looking for an antonym to go with it.

Imagine I have two boxes, one with phones which should be repaired and the second with others. I have to label each box with a single short word because the boxes are very small.

*Repairable* does not work because it describes things which *can* be repaired. So what are your recommendations?

Comment: I'm stuck on trying to imagine a box which can hold a number of phones to be repaired but which is too small to be labelled 'The contents of this box should be repaired'

Comment: Heh you have to picture BIG WRITING

Comment: Re-reading your first sentence, I feel the only possibility is "TO BE REPAIRED" or "REPAIR QUEUE"

Comment: Wait ... you say **"one contains phones which CAN be repaired"** then you say **"The word "repairable" is not suitable, because it describes things which CAN be repaired"**  This question is a waste of time.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, just an occasional mistake.

Comment: `Salvage` and `Spares` ?

Comment: @Frank I'd have to refer to a dictionary first if I was given those labeled boxes. :D but 1+.

Comment: Take a cue from Wonderland and write *FIXME*.  For the other one, how about just *OK*?

Comment: If you want to create a word (borrow from Latin): emendanda... literally thing which are needed/intended to be fixed

Comment: If the labeling is for your own use, just make up some words! bishnat can be ones that should be repaired. And monissa can be ones that shouldn't. (I apologize prematurely, and profusely if either of these words are offensive in any language)

Comment: Telegraphy operators were the best at brevity. The second box is FUBAR. The first one is SNAFU. I had crates under my lab bench with those labels. The FUBAR stuff was for the youngsters to play with. We were sorta hoping to fix the stuff in the SNAFU box some day. (ie., don't pull parts off something in the SNAFU box and use them to try to fix a FUBAR)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Broken.

For the other box, working.

If you are in the USA, you'll want something more complicated sounding. So: inoperative. Operative.

Comment: The potential problem with "broken" is that they could have another box containing broken stuff that can't or shouldn't be repaired (maybe being kept for spare parts). An alternative would be the less terminal-sounding "faulty".

Comment: Right.  I think her's looking for "To Be Repaired" or "Repair-shop inbox".  Note comment number four under the question - the whole question is a waste of time

Comment: "Operative" sounds great, but the wide variety of the meanings can lead to the misunderstanding. An imaginary repairmen *operates* with the broken phones, and the imaginary user *operates* with the good ones. 

So I take the "faulty", thank you.

Comment: I'm in the USA and I don't want anything more complicated-sounding. (Maybe if you are in the US _government_...) "Broken" is what I'd use.

Comment: "wide variety of the meanings" .... what? "operative" does not have a wide variety of meanings.  (Do you mean "some people may not know what it means..." ..?)

Answer (score 7):

You could label the box with any of the verbs *[fix](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fix#Verb)*, *[mend](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mend#Verb)*, *[fix up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fix_up#Verb)*, *[repair](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/repair#Verb)*, *[service](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/service#Verb)*, etc.

*Edit:* For a box with items in good working order, consider *[OK](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/OK#Adjective)* and *[good](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/good#Adjective)*.  For a box with items beyond hope, consider *[shot](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shot#Adjective)* (“(colloquial) Worn out or broken”) and *[parts](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/part#Noun)*.  You could have a box labeled *OK*, a box  labeled *Fix*, and a box labeled *Shot*.

Source for quotes and links: Wiktionary

Answer (score 2):

"To be" would make the form of the adjective that you want; in this case "To be repaired" or for a shorter one, "To be fixed", but as far as I know, English doesn't have that kind of structure to provide the adjective you want with a suffix or so.

Comment: You could also say "to fix". It means "to be fixed" and is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

For the box of things that *should be repaired* you could use *Salvage*

salvage transitive verb
: to save (something valuable or important) : to prevent the loss of (something)

"salvage." 2014.
In *Merriam-Webster.com.*
Retrieved July 8, 2014 `http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/salvage`

But this definition of *salvage* might be better

salvage

— n
2.  a. the act of saving any goods or property in danger of damage or destruction

Dictionary.com, "salvage," in *Collins English Dictionary - Complete & Unabridged 10th Edition*. Source location: HarperCollins Publishers. `http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/salvage`. Available: `http://dictionary.reference.com`. Accessed: July 08, 2014.

For the box of things that *should not be repaired* you could uses *Spares*

Spare
noun
20.
a spare thing, part, etc., as an extra tire for emergency use.

Dictionary.com, "Spares," in *Dictionary.com Unabridged*.Source location: Random House, Inc. `http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Spares`.Available: `http://dictionary.reference.com`.Accessed: July 08, 2014.

Comment: Weird, "salvage" to me has the opposite meaning - "don't try to repair these, but you might be able to salvage some parts from them".

Comment: @SteveBennet Same meaning really, it's just a matter of whether you salvage the whole thing or salvage parts from it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the clearest, shortest way to say it is **For Repair**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a word (borrow from Latin): emendanda - literally "things which are needed/intended to be fixed".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "reparanda", based on words such as "agenda" meaning "things requiring to be discussed", "Referenda" meaning "things requiring to be referred" and "memoranda" meaning "things requiring to be remembered" from the Latin gerund or gerundive.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with **save** and **strip**
Phones that can be saved go in the **save** bin,
others go in the **strip** bin to be stripped down into component pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Repair - for those that should be fixed.

NFG - for those that are No F*ing Good any more, but could be salvaged from.

Answer (score -1):

I will go for "For repair" as a label on the box.

Comment: How is "for repair" a single-word adjective, as the question requests?